# python subprocess issue with Nmap

Tags: python, subprocess, nmap

Im trying to get a linux binary to send its standard output to a variable by using subprocess. But just keep getting tracebacks.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>>nmap -sn -Pn todd.ns.cloudflare.com --script dns-check-zone --script-args='dns-check-zone.domain=www.macmonster.com
```

Any Ideas (oh and Im using Python2.7).

Ideally I would like to avoid using Shell=true to avoid any security concerns.

Thanks,

Comment: try splitting ""-sP -n 172.16.1.0/24" into separate list elements: "-sP","-n","172.16.1.0/24"

Comment: try: `check_output(shlex.split("/usr/bin/nmap -sP -n 172.16.1.0/24"))` import `shlex` module first`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### shlex to the rescue!

The module shlex will take a string containing the whole shell command and split it up exactly how Popen and check_output expect it. Like this:

```
import shlex, subprocess
cmd = "/usr/bin/nmap -sn -Pn todd.ns.cloudflare.com --script dns-check-zone --script-args='dns-check-zone.domain=www.macmonster.com'"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
```

When you look at contents of args you'll see:

```
>>> print args
['/usr/bin/nmap', '-sn', '-Pn', 'todd.ns.cloudflare.com', '--script', 'dns-check-zone', '--script-args=dns-check-zone.domain=www.macmonster.com']
```

Note that shlex split up the option "--script dns-check-zone" into two tokens. On the other hand it kept "--script-args='dns-check-zone.domain=www.macmonster.com'", but removed the single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/nmap", "-sP", "-n", "172.16.1.0/24"])

output = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/nmap", "-sP", "-n", "172.16.1.0/24"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, though the actual command I need to get working is : 
nmap -sn -Pn todd.ns.cloudflare.com --script dns-check-zone --script-args='dns-check-zone.domain=www.macmonster.com'

I treid splitting the commands out by no luck.

Comment: the principle is the same, each space separated thing should be a list element, you can put the commmand in a string, and the split the sprint and the feed it as input to check_output()

Comment: your command does not work on the cmd line for me either, so you must first fix the command

Comment: I imagine that the command doesnt work for you as you are not running nmap 6.25

Comment: Seems that only part of the nmap output is saved to the variable, but when I check it on the shell its fine and it seems to be sending the output to standard out (??)

Comment: it only captures the stdout by default, you have to add stderr=subprocess.STDOUT as an argument to get STDERR too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28847/discussion-between-felix001-and-uku-loskit)

Comment: I tried the suggestions but still no joy it appears that not all the output of subprocess is assigned to the variable (??)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
var = p.stdout.read()
print var
```

I would have used `communicate`, but it returns an odd list-type thing.